# How can I get the permutations for every number within range 1 to lst?

Tags: python, function, numbers, set, permutation

So I wrote this code that attempts to return all the permutations of a number in range (1, lst).

```
def permutation(lst):
    if isinstance(lst, int):
        lst = list(range(1, lst + 1))
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return ({(1,)})
    if len(lst) == 2:
        return ({(1,2),(2,1)})
    l = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        m = lst[i]
        remLst = lst[:i] + lst[i + 1:]
        for p in permutation(remLst):
            l.append(tuple([m] + list(p)))
    return set(l)
```

However, the output that I got seems to be incorrect.. because when I put in

```
permutation(3)
```

I get...

```
{(1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (3, 1, 2)}
```

but I'm supposed to get

```
{(1,2,3), (1,3,2), (2,1,3), (2,3,1), (3,1,2), (3,2,1)}
```

and when my input is `permutation(4)`
my output is

{(4, 1, 2, 1), (1, 4, 1, 2), (4, 1, 1, 2), (3, 1, 2, 1), (4, 3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2, 1), (4, 3, 1, 2), (3, 4, 2, 1), (3, 2, 1, 2), (4, 2, 2, 1), (3, 1, 1, 2), (3, 4, 1, 2), (2, 3, 2, 1), (4, 2, 1, 2), (2, 4, 1, 2), (2, 4, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2, 1), (1, 3, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 2, 1), (1, 4, 2, 1), (1, 3, 1, 2)}

but I'm supposed to get this...

{(4, 3, 1, 2), (3,4, 1, 2), (3, 1, 4, 2), (3, 1, 2,4),
(4, 1, 3, 2), (1, 4, 3, 2), (1, 3, 4, 2), (1, 3, 2, 4),
(4, 1, 2, 3), (1, 4, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4, 3), (1, 2, 3, 4),
(4, 3, 2, 1), (3, 4, 2, 1), (3, 2, 4, 1), (3, 2, 1, 4),
(4, 2, 3, 1), (2, 4, 3, 1), (2, 3, 4, 1), (2, 3, 1, 4),
(4, 2, 1, 3), (2, 4, 1, 3), (2, 1, 4, 3), (2, 1, 3, 4)}

What changes should I make so that my code returns the correct output??

Comment: Both are same right ? Do you want order of output to be same?

Comment: @ShashikamalRC it's not though. have a look at my output for permutations(2) and the expected output

Comment: @ShashikamalRC I mean permutations(3)

Comment: In the code `lst` is supposed to be a list, but you use 3 as argument. When you use 3, lst = [1, 2, 3] ?

Comment: @Melo yep, thats what I want. Its a list made from the range of 1 to the "lst" number

Comment: Have you checked the answer? I tested it and im fairly sure it works.

Comment: @jordanparker you should replace the handling of list with length 1 to: `return ({(lst[0],)})` and then remove the special handling of list with length 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.permutations`: it does exactly what you want to do.

```
from itertools import permutations

lst = 3
p = permutations(range(lst))
print(p)
```

See the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: thank u for ur response. However, I'm trying to not use built in functions like import, collections or itertools in my output. Is there a simpler way... like maybe from my code is there something I can change?

Comment: I see. The question should be about the implementation, and not about getting the permutations. I don't know if you can rephrase and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this

```
if len(lst) == 1:
    return ({(1,)})
if len(lst) == 2:
    return ({(1,2),(2,1)})
```

If the length of the list is 1, it doesn't necessarily mean that all its permutations will be 1. I think this messes up your recursion, try this instead:

```
if len(lst) == 1:
    return ({(lst[0],)})
if len(lst) == 2:
    return ({(lst[0],lst[1]),(lst[1],lst[0])})
```

Full code becomes:

```
def permutation(lst):
    if isinstance(lst, int):
        lst = list(range(1, lst + 1))
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return ({(lst[0],)})
    if len(lst) == 2:
        return ({(lst[0],lst[1]),(lst[1],lst[0])})
    l = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        m = lst[i]
        remLst = lst[:i] + lst[i + 1:]
        for p in permutation(remLst):
            l.append(tuple([m] + list(p)))
    return set(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative implementation of the `permutations` function:

```
def permutations(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return [lst]

    results = []

    for idx, item in enumerate(lst):
        sub_perms = permutations(lst[:idx] + lst[idx+1:])
        results.extend([item] + sub_perm for sub_perm in sub_perms)

    return results
```

Output for `permutations([1,2,3])`:

```
>>> permutations([1,2,3])
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple list comprehension, which might be a bit more pythonic.

```
def permutation(M):
    def permutation_set(S):
        if not S:
            return [[]]
        else:
            return [[x] + p for x in S for p in permutation_set(S - {x})] 
    return permutation_set(set(range(1, M+1)))

permutation(3)
# ==> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

The interpretation of this code is:

- Given a number M, compose a set `S = {1, 2, ..., M}` -- `set(range(1, M+1))`
- For each item `x` in set `S`, recursively generate permutations of a subset `S - {x}`
- Adjoin `x` to the front of each one of the permutations of the subset -- `[x] + p for p in permutation_set(S - {x})`

This yields for each `x` in `S`, the sequence of permutations of `S` that begin with `x`.

Traversing through all `x` gives all permutations of `S` -- `[x] + p for x in S`